# Python Pandas Export -> Adding Tab to Lines

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to add tab to a tex data and export as excel csv and txt files. I have:

```
13 turned in the research Paper 
on Friday; otherwise, he Would 
have not passed the Class
```

and I want to add tab before last word. I wrote this code:

```
df = df.replace({"\s([A-Z][a-z]+[a-z])$": " \\t\\1"}, regex=True)
df.to_csv("file.csv", sep='\t')
df.to_csv("file.txt", sep='\t', index=False)
df.to_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

the problem is when I export and look the files I have *"*s which are not in original file and in excel file, whole lines stays in one column rather than two column.

```
"13 turned in the research Paper" 
"on Friday; otherwise, he Would" 
"have not passed the Class"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `r'\\t'` or `'\\\\t'`, here is how I did it.

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import re

#create the sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'sent':['13 turned in the research Paper',\
                          'on Friday; otherwise, he Would',\
                          'have not passed the Class']})

#df.head()

#apply regex substitution
df['sent'] = df['sent'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\s([A-Z][a-z]+$)', r'\\t\g<1>', x))

df.to_csv('tabbed.txt',index=False)

'''
sent
13 turned in the research\tPaper
"on Friday; otherwise, he\tWould"
have not passed the\tClass
'''

#not-so-pretty output
pd.read_csv('tabbed.txt', sep=r'\\t', engine='python')

'''
                            sent
13 turned in the research   Paper
"on Friday; otherwise, he   Would"
have not passed the         Class
'''
```

Prettified output

```
#prettify it
(pd.read_csv('tabbed.txt', sep='\\\\t', engine='python')
 .reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'sent0','sent':'sent1'})
 .replace(r'"', '', regex=True)
)

'''
    sent0                       sent1
0   13 turned in the research   Paper
1   on Friday; otherwise, he    Would
2   have not passed the         Class
'''
```